# How to reduce jquery.min.js CPU time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, profiling

I've noticed that almost all my browser's Javascript CPU resources get spent on jquery.min.js, specifically loaded from :

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
```

Are there any tool to minimize the resources consumed by JavaScript generally and/or jQuery specifically without outright blacklisting specific scripts?

I suppose the most obvious approach would be dynamically reducing the number of timer and other events a script receives.  In fact, you could probably halt all events to scripts not in the foreground page, except for a specific whitelist of sites you actually want to permit to receive events in the background.

I'm perfectly happy with Javascript performance going way down so long as overall browser performance improves.

Comment: how many "shiny" effects are you using? jQuery itself is not a problem since it does not fire until you use it.

Comment: Strange question :)... Do you want javascript to run slower ? Is it your javascript or other sites that you are visiting ?

Comment: Yes, I want javascript to consume less resources across all websites.  jQuery might be an easy way to tune their resource consumption because it's used so universally.

Comment: I should probably simply play around with modifying the timer events routines in jquery.min.js, but I asked if anyone has already thought about it enough to make greasemonkey scripts or whatever.

Comment: You notice a dramatic improvement in browser performance if you simply blacklist ajax.googleapis.com, but obviously ajax stuff sops working then.  It'd be useful to find a middle ground where the timer events were slowed down to the point that the browser's performance wasn't quite so negatively impacted, but basically stuff still worked, although timed stuff would occur less frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like there is another script using jquery to do specific tasks.  The jquery script itself after loading in the browser, to my knowledge, does not use any additional resource after that point in time.

Based my assumption of what is happening, there is nothing you can do at the moment (specifically because you haven't provided enough information to help).

Comment: This is not really an answer (even if the question i strange), is it ?

Comment: I believe my statement *there is nothing you can do at the moment* is an answer to the question *How to reduce jquery.min.js CPU time*?.

Comment: I'm satisfied what I want doesn't already exist.  I'll play around with dramatically slowing down setTimeout and setInterval based events using GreaseMonkey and NinjaKit.

Answer (score 0):

Change all the getElementsByClassName to getElementsByTagName. This will improve the performance drastically as the getElementsByTagName is more efficient